Create an instance of a .NET class in C++ using hostfxr
Using public APIs, is it possible to create an instance of a .NET class in C++ using hostfxr and invoke its methods, or just call static .NET methods?
I am able to call static methods successfully. Looking at the headers nethost.h, coreclr_delegates.h and hostfxr.h doesn't reveal any obvious APIs.
====
After some experimenting, the closest method I can find is having a native implementation of the class, then passing the native this pointer to a static .NET method that creates an instance of the class in the .NET context that saves the this pointer. Each time a method is called on that class, it simply calls back into the native context using a [DllImport] method that passes the this pointer along with any arguments.

I voted to close this QA by mistake - it should be reopened, because since .NET 5 and .NET 8 the answer now is yes it is now possible (and I dare say, straightforward) for host-side C/C++ code to invoke not only static methods, but also to load and instantiate classes and invoke instance members on them.

Look for hdt_get_function_pointer, hdt_load_assembly_and_get_function_pointer, and hdt_load_assembly_bytes, and more besides.
